# It is very slow only when the spring data jpa repository related code is executed for the first time after running the application

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

When building and running spring boot 2.1.12 using spring data jpa, the first execution speed of jpa related repository code is very slow. (Especially **insert query**)

```java
@Transaction
public InjectInventory initInsertInjectInventory() {
    InjectInventory injectInventory = InjectInventory
            .builder()
            .gsn(1)
            .usn(453l)
            .itemId("1111")
            .gameItemId("5000")
            .status("N")
            .inType(2)
            .cdlId("TESTJMLIMITEM").build();

    return injectInventoryRepository.save(injectInventory);
}
```

When I run the above `initInsertInjectInventory()` method for the first time, jpa insert occurs on that table and it is very slow.
It is not slow to rerun the same method afterwards.

Applications must continue to scale out or relaunch. So that matters.
I want to get rid of this phenomenon.
Which part should I check?

======================

example)

1. Controller code

```java
@Slf4j
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/panda")
public class TestController {
    .....
    @GetMapping("/xpi/insert-inject-inventory")
    @ResponseBody
    public String initInsertInjectInventory() {
        StopWatch sw = new StopWatch();

        sw.start();

        testService.initInsertInjectInventory();
        sw.stop();


        long totalTimeMillis = sw.getTotalTimeMillis();
        String returnText = "targetTable : inject_inven_ut, totalTimeMillis: " + totalTimeMillis + "ms";
        return returnText;
    }
}
```

2. Call URL : http://localhost:18060/panda/xpi/insert-inject-inventory
3. Log remaining on call (first call, Response time 2734ms)

```java
2020-07-29 18:01:41.236  INFO 87633 --- [io-18060-exec-1] .c.core.ContainerBase.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/].log : Initializing Spring DispatcherServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2020-07-29 18:01:41.236  INFO 87633 --- [io-18060-exec-1] work.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.initServletBean : Initializing Servlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2020-07-29 18:01:41.256  INFO 87633 --- [io-18060-exec-1] work.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.initServletBean : Completed initialization in 20 ms
2020-07-29 18:01:43.993 DEBUG 87633 --- [io-18060-exec-1] org.hibernate.SQL.logStatement                     : 
    /* insert io.jmlim.app.panda.application.inventory.domain.InjectInventory
        */ insert 
        into
            inject_inven_ut
            (cdl_id, game_item_id, gsn, in_type, item_id, status, usn) 
        values
            (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
Hibernate: 
    /* insert io.jmlim.app.panda.application.inventory.domain.InjectInventory
        */ insert 
        into
            inject_inven_ut
            (cdl_id, game_item_id, gsn, in_type, item_id, status, usn) 
        values
            (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
2020-07-29 18:01:44.023 TRACE 87633 --- [io-18060-exec-1] org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder.bind : binding parameter [1] as [VARCHAR] - [TESTJMLIMITEM]
2020-07-29 18:01:44.024 TRACE 87633 --- [io-18060-exec-1] org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder.bind : binding parameter [2] as [VARCHAR] - [5000]
2020-07-29 18:01:44.031 TRACE 87633 --- [io-18060-exec-1] org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder.bind : binding parameter [3] as [INTEGER] - [1]
2020-07-29 18:01:44.032 TRACE 87633 --- [io-18060-exec-1] org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder.bind : binding parameter [4] as [INTEGER] - [2]
2020-07-29 18:01:44.032 TRACE 87633 --- [io-18060-exec-1] org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder.bind : binding parameter [5] as [VARCHAR] - [1111]
2020-07-29 18:01:44.033 TRACE 87633 --- [io-18060-exec-1] org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder.bind : binding parameter [6] as [VARCHAR] - [N]
2020-07-29 18:01:44.034 TRACE 87633 --- [io-18060-exec-1] org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder.bind : binding parameter [7] as [BIGINT] - [453]
2020-07-29 18:01:44.079  INFO 87633 --- [io-18060-exec-1] o.h.e.i.StatisticalLoggingSessionEventListener.end : Session Metrics {
    7239652 nanoseconds spent acquiring 1 JDBC connections;
    0 nanoseconds spent releasing 0 JDBC connections;
    26426029 nanoseconds spent preparing 1 JDBC statements;
    6874533 nanoseconds spent executing 1 JDBC statements;
    0 nanoseconds spent executing 0 JDBC batches;
    0 nanoseconds spent performing 0 L2C puts;
    0 nanoseconds spent performing 0 L2C hits;
    0 nanoseconds spent performing 0 L2C misses;
    3823210 nanoseconds spent executing 1 flushes (flushing a total of 1 entities and 0 collections);
    0 nanoseconds spent executing 0 partial-flushes (flushing a total of 0 entities and 0 collections)
}
2020-07-29 18:01:44.102  INFO 87633 --- [io-18060-exec-1] ceptor.JmlimControllerInterceptor.afterCompletion : GET /panda/xpi/insert-inject-inventory (2734ms)
```

4. On the second call (Response time: 60ms)

```java
2020-07-29 18:15:28.542 DEBUG 87633 --- [io-18060-exec-4] org.hibernate.SQL.logStatement                     : 
    /* insert io.jmlim.app.panda.application.inventory.domain.InjectInventory
        */ insert 
        into
            inject_inven_ut
            (cdl_id, game_item_id, gsn, in_type, item_id, status, usn) 
        values
            (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
Hibernate: 
    /* insert io.jmlim.app.panda.application.inventory.domain.InjectInventory
        */ insert 
        into
            inject_inven_ut
            (cdl_id, game_item_id, gsn, in_type, item_id, status, usn) 
        values
            (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
2020-07-29 18:15:28.543 TRACE 87633 --- [io-18060-exec-4] org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder.bind : binding parameter [1] as [VARCHAR] - [TESTJMLIMITEM]
2020-07-29 18:15:28.544 TRACE 87633 --- [io-18060-exec-4] org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder.bind : binding parameter [2] as [VARCHAR] - [5000]
2020-07-29 18:15:28.544 TRACE 87633 --- [io-18060-exec-4] org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder.bind : binding parameter [3] as [INTEGER] - [1]
2020-07-29 18:15:28.544 TRACE 87633 --- [io-18060-exec-4] org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder.bind : binding parameter [4] as [INTEGER] - [2]
2020-07-29 18:15:28.545 TRACE 87633 --- [io-18060-exec-4] org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder.bind : binding parameter [5] as [VARCHAR] - [1111]
2020-07-29 18:15:28.545 TRACE 87633 --- [io-18060-exec-4] org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder.bind : binding parameter [6] as [VARCHAR] - [N]
2020-07-29 18:15:28.545 TRACE 87633 --- [io-18060-exec-4] org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder.bind : binding parameter [7] as [BIGINT] - [453]
2020-07-29 18:15:28.572  INFO 87633 --- [io-18060-exec-4] o.h.e.i.StatisticalLoggingSessionEventListener.end : Session Metrics {
    7397456 nanoseconds spent acquiring 1 JDBC connections;
    0 nanoseconds spent releasing 0 JDBC connections;
    539633 nanoseconds spent preparing 1 JDBC statements;
    12771277 nanoseconds spent executing 1 JDBC statements;
    0 nanoseconds spent executing 0 JDBC batches;
    0 nanoseconds spent performing 0 L2C puts;
    0 nanoseconds spent performing 0 L2C hits;
    0 nanoseconds spent performing 0 L2C misses;
    223073 nanoseconds spent executing 1 flushes (flushing a total of 1 entities and 0 collections);
    0 nanoseconds spent executing 0 partial-flushes (flushing a total of 0 entities and 0 collections)
}
2020-07-29 18:15:28.576  INFO 87633 --- [io-18060-exec-4] ceptor.SummerControllerInterceptor.afterCompletion : GET /panda/xpi/insert-inject-inventory (60ms)
```

#### Additional discoveries

The log attached to the body is the entire log when the URL is executed.

There is an additional phenomenon. It only occurs when packaging with a "war" file.

(ex: apply plugin:'war' setting in build.gradle)

After changing the settings to build with "jar" and testing again, the above does not occur and it is faster from the beginning.
Is it a bug? Or is there an option that needs to be modified or added?

Comment: Do you see anything in the log? Do you see the executed SQL? How is InjectInventory mapped?

Comment: @Simon Martinelli Execution code and log were added and updated in the body.

And if you change the above method to jpa NativeQuery, it does not occur and it is faster from the beginning.
Please refer.

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: I use Mysql. The version is 8.0.15.

Comment: If I have a look at the logs I see that the lost time is between 18:01:41.256 and 2020-07-29 18:01:43.993 Can you turn on debug log for web and hibernate

Comment: @Simon Martinelli 
The log attached to the body is the entire log when the URL is executed.

There is an additional phenomenon. It only occurs when packaging with a "war" file.

(ex: apply plugin:'war' setting in build.gradle)

After changing the settings to build with "jar" and testing again, the above does not occur and it is faster from the beginning.
Is it a bug? Or is there an option that needs to be modified or added?

Comment: That's hard to say. 2.1.12 is a rather old version. Did you try with a more recent version?

Comment: After upgrading to the latest version of Spring Boot (2.3.2-RELEASE), I tested it and the performance improved a little.
(It has improved from 3 seconds to 2.5 seconds.)

But it doesn't seem to be a significant improvement. For reference, the Java version is 1.8.0_252.

Comment: packaging with a "jar" file, the first call speed is 0.3 seconds.